# Sorting array of objects using localeCompare with possible false for value

Tags: javascript

I'm making a sorting function where sort by value will be dynamic and some values of properties in objects in the array can be false.

I Would like to use `localeCompare` due to possible special characters etc.

As seen in the example it breaks if a `false` value is in the middle of the array. I did try to implement optional changing but it does not work at all then:

```
return a.sortValue?.[1].localeCompare(b.sortValue?.[1])
```

The expected results Is:

for `user_id`:
4
1
2
3

and `partner_id`:
4
1
3
2

Sort value is always (when not false) in 1 index of the array.
And would like `false` at the end, I still need it in the list...

Is this possible without making some custom sorting function?

```js
let arr = [{
    id: 1,
    user_id: ["ignoreThis", 'B'],
    partner_id: ["ignoreThis", 'B']
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    user_id: ["ignoreThis", 'D'],
    partner_id: false
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    user_id: false,
    partner_id: ["ignoreThis", 'D']
  },
   {
    id: 4,
    user_id: ["ignoreThis", 'A'],
    partner_id: ["ignoreThis", 'A']
  }
]

const sortBy = sortValue => {
  arr.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a[sortValue][1].localeCompare(b[sortValue][1])
  })
}

sortBy('user_id')
arr.forEach(i => console.log(i.id))
sortBy('partner_id')
arr.forEach(i => console.log(i.id))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  min-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could check the value first and the sort by the wanted value. This approach needs a default empty string for using `localeCompare`.

```js
const
    array = [{ id: 1, user_id: ["ignoreThis", 'B'], partner_id: ["ignoreThis", 'B'] }, { id: 2, user_id: ["ignoreThis", 'D'], partner_id: false }, { id: 3, user_id: false, partner_id: ["ignoreThis", 'D'] }, { id: 4, user_id: ["ignoreThis", 'A'], partner_id: ["ignoreThis", 'A'] }] 
    sortBy = key => array.sort((a, b) =>
        !a[key] - !b[key] ||
        (a[key]?.[1] || '').localeCompare(b[key]?.[1])
    );

sortBy('user_id');
console.log(...array.map(({ id }) => id));
sortBy('partner_id');
console.log(...array.map(({ id }) => id));
```